# Animating long sequences in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have to make a long animation with jQuery, full of fadeOuts,fadeIns,slideIns,...

The problem I am having is that my code looks ugly and it is full of callback. 
Also, if I want to stop animation for some time like: `slideOut->wait 5 seconds->slideIn` I have to use delay and I am not sure if that is the best practice.

**Example**:

```
/* Slides */
var slide1 = $('div#slide1'),
    slide2 = $('div#slide2'),
    slide3 = $('div#slide3');

$(document).ready(function(){
    slide1.fadeIn(function(){
        slide2.fadeIn(function(){
            slide3.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut(function(){
                slide2.fadeOut(function(){
                    slide1.fadeOut();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**JSFIddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZPvrD/6/

**Question**: Is there any other way of building animations in jQuery, possibly even some great plugin to help me solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest trying the queue method: http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the plugin you were looking for :) Does the exact same thing, but is much more flexible than your existing code http://jsfiddle.net/ZPvrD/11/

```
(function($){
    $.fn.fadeInOut = function(middleDelay) {
        middleDelay = middleDelay || 0; 
        var index = 0,
            direction = 1, // 1: fading in; -1: fading out        
            me = this,
            size = me.size();
        function nextAnimation() {
            // Before the first element, we're done
            if (index === -1 )  { return; }

            var currentEl = $(me.get(index)),
                goingForward = direction === 1,
                isLastElement = index === (size - 1);

            // Change direction for the next animation, don't update index
            // since next frame will fade the same element out
            if (isLastElement && goingForward) {
                direction = -1;
            } else {
                index += direction;
            }

            // At the last element, before starting to fade out, add a delay 
            if ( isLastElement && !goingForward) {
                currentEl.delay(middleDelay);
            }
            if (goingForward) {
                currentEl.fadeIn(nextAnimation);
            } else {
                currentEl.fadeOut(nextAnimation);                    
            }
        }
        nextAnimation();
        return this;
    }        
})(jQuery);
```

And you call it like

```
$('div.slideWrapper>div.slide').fadeInOut(3000);
```

This process of traversing up and down a list of jQuery elements waiting for each animation to finish could be abstracted so that it could be used for other things besides `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. I'll leave that for you to try out if you feel adventurous.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 /* Slides */
 var slide = $('div[id*="slide"]');

 $( function(){

      slide.each( function( k ){

            $( this ).delay( 500 * k ).fadeIn();
      });
  });
```

Comment: hm.. what about fadeOut :P

Comment: And it's cheating, assuming you know the default animation delay. You could use the same assumption and add a different loop calling `fadeOut` backwards.

Answer (score -1):

JQuery animations take two parameters (maximum), duration and complete, duration is the time in milliseconds for how long you want your animation to complete, or you can use "slow" or "fast", and the second params complete which is the callback function.

If don't want to use delay, you may make the previous animation slow.

e.g.

```
slide1.fadeIn(5000, function(){
    slide2.fadeIn();
};
```

Comment: this is not the same as delay..this will just "strech" the animation over 5 seconds..

Comment: That's true, and that's what I meant If don't want to use delay!

Comment: Even if I don't want to use delay, this is still not the same.Delay and duration time are two different things. Delay stops the execution of function for a period of time where duration time parameter just streches an animation over a period of time. If i used your code, the next function after fade is done, would still run immediately :)